# How to make an element scroll with user and remain on same side using bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get a category bar for blogs to remain on screen on scroll and remain on the right side. The problem is that my current method is making the bar switch the right side AND shrink down when you scroll past the first article. I am using Bootstrap version 4 in my styles, so it probably has something to do with the grid system.

I searched online and found a question referring to JSS with the link included below but I am having a hard time implementing a solution with it. The documentation isn't that great so its hard to figure out if I am activating it. Github found at https://github.com/dvtng/jss.

```js
var prevWidth = $(window).width();

if ($(window).width() > 767) {
  $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
    "use strict";
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
  }, function() {
    "use strict";
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
  });

  $('.navbar .dropdown > a').click(function() {
    "use strict";
    location.href = this.href;
  });
}


var $window = $(window),
  $stickydiv = $('#cat-div'),
  $divTop = $stickydiv.offset().top,
  $pos = $stickydiv.position(),
  $posleft = $pos.left;
/*jss.set('.sticky', {
    'left': $posleft
});*/

$window.scroll(function() {
  $stickydiv.toggleClass('sticky', $window.scrollTop() > $divTop);
});

window.onresize = function() {
  "use strict";

  if ($(window).width() < 767 && prevWidth > 767) {
    location.reload();
    setNewHeight();
  } else if ($(window).width() > 767 && prevWidth < 767) {
    location.reload();
    setNewHeight();
  }
  /* $pos = $stickydiv.position();
   $posleft = $pos.left;
   jss.set('.sticky', {
       'left': $posleft
   });*/
};

function setNewHeight() {
  "use strict";
  prevWidth = $(window).width();
}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

.title {
  font-family: vatican;
}

.soph {
  font-family: Sophisto;
}

.of-auto {
  overflow: auto;
}

#cat-div.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 63px;
}

div.splat {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="title">Explore The Blog</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="well of-auto">
        <h3 class="title">Some Title <small>February 2, 2018</small></h3>
        <p class="soph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
          quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras
          dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus
          varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing
          sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt.
          Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 well splat" id="cat-div">
      <nav class="nav flex-column">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Category</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Category</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Category</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link disabled">Category</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="well of-auto">
        <h3 class="title">Another Title <small>February 1, 2018</small></h3>
        <p class="soph">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
          quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam
          eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit
          qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti
          quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero
          tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="well of-auto">
        <h3 class="title">Final Title <small>January 31, 2018</small></h3>
        <p class="soph">But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder
          of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone
          who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious
          physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure? On the
          other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="well of-auto">
          <h3 class="title">Another Title <small>February 1, 2018</small></h3>
          <p class="soph">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
            quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam
            eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure
            reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti
            atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.
            Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="well of-auto">
          <h3 class="title">Final Title <small>January 31, 2018</small></h3>
          <p class="soph">But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder
            of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone
            who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious
            physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure? On
            the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It would help if you could distil your question to just the thing you want resolving - and only show us the applicable portions of code. Is this what you want to solve: 'how can I make a div stay in the same position as the user scrolls down'? A screenshot of what's going wrong would probably easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks for that. I will comment again once I have edited that. I took a look at that and I see what you mean. I wouldn't want to answer this question either if it looked like this.

Comment: I have cleaned it up. If I need to dilute it more, let me know.

Comment: @TylerLazenby Here's what I recommend you do if you want me to help you troubleshoot and fix this issue: Replace all of the PHP snippets with one snippet for HTML *output*. Just one page where the issue occurs. Open a browser window, view source and copy **all** of the output HTML from there (including links to css, CDNs and JavaScript). PHP has absolutely nothing to do with this issue, so you might as well remove the PHP tag from the question. PHP might come into play once the issue is fixed but until then it doesn't matter.

Comment: Good Idea, I will do that in a moment.

Comment: I have finished cleaning it up.

Comment: Has any of available answers answered your question? :)

Comment: Well i don't quite know how bootstrap is making it act like this, i do know that bootstrap is part of the obstacles, but unsure how since my styles should be overriding bootstrap as it is added AFTER the css sheet... could be that a jQuery is overriding afterwards though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first let's acknowledge the basic problem you are going to have to overcome here: when your page first loads, your category bar's size and position is based on it being a child element of a parent that's `display: flex`. But as soon as you scroll down, it becomes `position: fixed`, meaning it is taken out of the flow of the document. As such, its position and size will change because it is no longer the child of a flex element.

So what you really need to do is one of two things. Either:

1. Make the category bar `position: fixed` from the start, so you don't have to worry about it looking different when the page first loads vs when you scroll down. Or,
2. Mimic its initial style once it becomes fixed, so it looks the same.

Mimicing its position is relatively easy with just a couple extra CSS rules. For example, on desktop, we can see that being `16.666666%` wide, as the `.col-md-2` class dictates, results in the bar being 190px wide. So your `.stuck` class can include `width: 190px` to make sure the width is maintained.

Then we can calculate its distance from the right side of the page and use that in our `.stuck` class as well. Since `.container` takes up `1140px` of our page, that means there's `(100% - 1140px)` of space left on the sides of the document. Divide that by two, and you get the distance from the right of the screen that your sidebar is.

Putting it together, you get this:

```
#cat-div.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 63px;
  right: calc(calc(100% - 1140px) / 2); /* new */
  width: 190px; /* new */
}
```

Now our bar will stay in place when you scroll down.

The height problem is trickier to solve. Flexbox will make your sidebar expand to as tall as the paragraph next to it. That's fine as long as your paragraph is taller than your sidebar, but what if it's not? Probably better to give it a fixed height that will contain its links, so it doesn't appear to shrink when you scroll down.

```
div.splat {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  height: 200px; /* new */
}
```

The last thing you may want to change is how the sticking works. If you want it to stick to the top of the screen as you scroll down, change your `top` value on `#cat-div.sticky` from `63px` to `0`, and you'll be good to go. If you want it to appear to stay the same distance from the top of the screen, you'll need to find its top value when the page first loads (similar to how we found its width and right position) and set the `top` value to that amount when its stuck in place. Then you need to change the JavaScript to add the stuck class immediately if you scroll even 1px, rather than waiting til it hits the top of the screen.

So this:

```
$stickydiv.toggleClass('sticky', $window.scrollTop() > $divTop);
```

Becomes:

```
$stickydiv.toggleClass('sticky', $window.scrollTop() > 0);
```

And you can also get rid of the `$divTop` variable then, since you won't need it any more.

**Putting it all together:**

```js
var prevWidth = $(window).width();

if ($(window).width() > 767) {
    $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function () {
        "use strict";
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
    }, function () {
        "use strict";
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
    });

    $('.navbar .dropdown > a').click(function(){
        "use strict";
        location.href = this.href;
    });
}


var $window = $(window),
    $stickydiv = $('#cat-div'),
    //$divTop = $stickydiv.offset().top,
    $pos = $stickydiv.position(),
    $posleft = $pos.left;
    /*jss.set('.sticky', {
        'left': $posleft
    });*/

$window.scroll(function () {
    $stickydiv.toggleClass('sticky', $window.scrollTop() > 0);
});

window.onresize = function(){
    "use strict";

    if ($(window).width() < 767 && prevWidth > 767) {
        location.reload();
        setNewHeight();
    } else if ($(window).width() > 767 && prevWidth < 767) {
        location.reload();
        setNewHeight();
    }
   /* $pos = $stickydiv.position();
    $posleft = $pos.left;
    jss.set('.sticky', {
        'left': $posleft
    });*/
};
function setNewHeight() {
    "use strict";
    prevWidth = $(window).width();
}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
.title {
  font-family: vatican;
}
.soph {
  font-family: Sophisto;
}
.of-auto {
  overflow: auto;
}
#cat-div.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 46px;
  right: calc(calc(100% - 1140px) / 2);
  width: 190px;
}
div.splat {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <h2 class="title">Explore The Blog</h2>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10">
   <div class="well of-auto">
    <h3 class="title">Some Title <small>February 2, 2018</small></h3>
    <p class="soph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 well splat" id="cat-div">
   <nav class="nav flex-column">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Category</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Category</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Category</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link disabled">Category</a>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10">
   <div class="well of-auto">
    <h3 class="title">Another Title <small>February 1, 2018</small></h3>
    <p class="soph">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10">
   <div class="well of-auto">
    <h3 class="title">Final Title <small>January 31, 2018</small></h3>
    <p class="soph">But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure? On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10">
   <div class="well of-auto">
    <h3 class="title">Another Title <small>February 1, 2018</small></h3>
    <p class="soph">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10">
   <div class="well of-auto">
    <h3 class="title">Final Title <small>January 31, 2018</small></h3>
    <p class="soph">But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure? On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Applause and honor to you sir! This is a perfect solution with a great explaination.

Comment: Also want to let you know that I am attributing the fix to you on the code, any formal name I should put?

Comment: @TylerLazenby thanks for asking, but simply linking to this answer would be fine.

Comment: I just tried implementing the solution into the real thing... i don't understand why it's not doing what the example showed

Comment: @TylerLazenby What part specifically is not working?

Comment: It's doing exactly what it was doing  before. It will scroll but switch sides and shrink

Comment: @TylerLazenby sounds like your CSS isn't working then. First verify that styles in your stylesheet are actually being applied (e.g., you didn't forget to link to them in your HTML or something). Then use your browser's developer tools to make sure the CSS is targeting the right elements and isn't getting overridden by something else. Once you do that stuff, you can ask a new question with more specific details if need be.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's bootstrap because I've removed the css altogether other and making the position fixed and it did exactly the same thing. I'm gonna rip and rebuild from the ground up on this one

Answer (score 0):

Look at your menu:

```
<div class="col-md-2 well splat" id="cat-div">
  <nav class="nav flex-column">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Category</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Category</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Category</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link disabled">Category</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

You are basically taking whole `col-md-2` from your grid and you are trying to make it fixed.

If you really just want to make the navigation sticky to the right side of the screen all you have to do is set `right: 0;` in your CSS.

However, I would advise you to change your page structure a little.

```js
var prevWidth = $(window).width();

if ($(window).width() > 767) {
  $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
    "use strict";
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
  }, function() {
    "use strict";
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
  });

  $('.navbar .dropdown > a').click(function() {
    "use strict";
    location.href = this.href;
  });
}


var $window = $(window),
  $stickydiv = $('#cat-div'),
  $divTop = $stickydiv.offset().top,
  $pos = $stickydiv.position(),
  $posleft = $pos.left;
/*jss.set('.sticky', {
    'left': $posleft
});*/

$window.scroll(function() {
  $stickydiv.toggleClass('sticky', $window.scrollTop() > $divTop);
});

window.onresize = function() {
  "use strict";

  if ($(window).width() < 767 && prevWidth > 767) {
    location.reload();
    setNewHeight();
  } else if ($(window).width() > 767 && prevWidth < 767) {
    location.reload();
    setNewHeight();
  }
  /* $pos = $stickydiv.position();
   $posleft = $pos.left;
   jss.set('.sticky', {
       'left': $posleft
   });*/
};

function setNewHeight() {
  "use strict";
  prevWidth = $(window).width();
}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

.title {
  font-family: vatican;
}

.soph {
  font-family: Sophisto;
}

.of-auto {
  overflow: auto;
}

#cat-div.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 63px;
  right: 0;
}

div.splat {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="title">Explore The Blog</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="well of-auto">
        <h3 class="title">Some Title <small>February 2, 2018</small></h3>
        <p class="soph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
          quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras
          dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus
          varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing
          sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt.
          Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 well splat" id="cat-div">
      <nav class="nav flex-column">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Category</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Category</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Category</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link disabled">Category</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="well of-auto">
        <h3 class="title">Another Title <small>February 1, 2018</small></h3>
        <p class="soph">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
          quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam
          eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit
          qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti
          quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero
          tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="well of-auto">
        <h3 class="title">Final Title <small>January 31, 2018</small></h3>
        <p class="soph">But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder
          of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone
          who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious
          physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure? On the
          other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="well of-auto">
          <h3 class="title">Another Title <small>February 1, 2018</small></h3>
          <p class="soph">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
            quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam
            eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure
            reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti
            atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.
            Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="well of-auto">
          <h3 class="title">Final Title <small>January 31, 2018</small></h3>
          <p class="soph">But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder
            of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone
            who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious
            physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure? On
            the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```